# Chernoff Bound. Inequalities like $P(Y \ge 150) \le e^{-50log(\frac{27}{16})} $ .

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_1, X_2 , ...,X_{200} $ be independent Bernoulli random variables.

In other words: $X_i$ ~ $Ber(\frac{1}{2}$) for $ i \in $ {1,...,200}.

Define $ Y = \sum_{i=1}^{200} X_i $.

Given: $Y$ ~ $Bin(200,\frac{1}{2}) $.

Show that:

a) $ P(Y \ge 150) \le \frac{2}{3} $

b) for every $ t$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ :
$\mathbb{E}(e^{t Y}) $ = $ e^{200log(\frac{1}{2}e^t+\frac{1}{2})} $

c) for every $t$ $\in \mathbb{R}$ : $P(Y \ge 150) \le e^{-150t+200log(\frac{1}{2}e^t+\frac{1}{2})} $

d) Find the optimal $t$ and show that: $P(Y \ge 150) \le e^{-50log(\frac{27}{16})}  $

My attempt:

a) Solved this with Markov's inequality.

b) $\mathbb{E}(e^{t Y}) = \mathbb{E}(e^{t \sum_{i=1}^{200} X_i }) = \mathbb{E}(e^{ \sum_{i=1}^{200} t  X_i }) = \mathbb{E}( \prod_{i=1}^{200}e^{t  X_i }) $ . I know that $X_i$ is independent. But how do I know that $ e^{tX_i}$ is independent? Anyways now I'm using the independence: $ \prod_{i=1}^{200} \mathbb{E}(e^{t  X_i }).$ Now I need that: $\mathbb{E}( e^{t  X_i }) = \frac{1}{2}e^t+\frac{1}{2}.$ Can someone explain me why this equality holds? The rest of b) is clear.

c) I was able to show this for $t > 0 $: $P(Y \ge 150)= P(e^{tY} > e^{t150})$. Use Markov's inequality: So $P(e^{tY} > e^{t150}) < \frac{1}{e^{t150}} \mathbb{E}(e^{t Y}) = e^{-150t+200log(\frac{1}{2}e^t+\frac{1}{2})}.$ What can I do for $t \le 0 $?

d) Unfortunately I have no idea for this part.

I hope you can help me. :) Edit: c) is clear now because I have to show 
this inequality only for $ t \ge 0 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b) The independence comes from a standard theorem that if $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ are independent, then $f_1(X_1), f_2(x_2), \dots, f_n(X_n)$ are independent for any functions $f_i$. For the expectations, try the [Law of the Unconscious Statistician:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)
$$\mathbb E[e^{t X_i}] = e^{t \cdot 1} \cdot \frac 1 2 + e^{t \cdot 0} \cdot \frac 1 2.$$

c) Show that when $t < 0$, the exponent on $e$ is positive, hence the bound is trivial.

d) Hint: Recall from early calculus how to find optimal values of functions; the upshot is always to take a derivative, set it to 0, and solve.

**Editing** to expand this hint: Suppose you wanted to optimize the function $f(x) = -3x^2 + 5x + 7$. In this case, "optimize" would mean "maximize," although in general it could refer to a max or a min depending on the context. For differentiable functions, maxima and minima can occur only where there are horizontal tangents. Here, that would mean setting $0 = f'(x) = -6x + 5$ to obtain $x = 5/6$, the $x$-coordinate of the maximum value.

In your problem, your task is to optimize the function $f(x) = e^{-150t + 200 \log(\frac 1 2 e^t + \frac 1 2 )}$. Since the function $e^x$ is an increasing function, it attains a maximum (or minimum) where its exponent does. Thus, your task is actually to optimize the function $g(x) = -150t + 200 \log(\frac 1 2 e^t + \frac 1 2)$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: a), b) and c) are clear. ( The situation in c) has changed. I have to show this inequality only for $ t \ge 0 $. :) But to be honest: I don't understand your hint in d). I'm sorry I'm kind of at a loss here.

Comment: I've expanded the hint significantly; let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think that I finally get your hint. I solved it. $ t = log(3) $. :)